# Creating a separate package for tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Is it feasible/possible/a good idea, when developing a package, to put tests in a completely separate package? I would also use the package for factories and seeding for development also. I have an app which is made up of a number of different packages (API, frontend, backend - coded by myself). I've not seen this done before and Google doesn't seem to yield any results but it seems to be "technically" possible. Any pitfalls or advice to dissuade me (or otherwise) against this?

Comment: Can you clarify why would you want to separate tests from the codebase?

Comment: More for organization really. I like the idea that tests are kept out of the codebase (if that's possible). Also the use of seeders and factories don't feel like they should be in my packages at all but I would like them to test things out while developing.

Comment: Also, and this is more of a convenience thing, I could run a suite of tests for all three packages at the same time but it is more about the organization than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to see that you are testing your project and also thinking about doing it in an efficient manner. I think it may help if you read the [Laravel docs on testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing) as Laravel does include some neat features out of the box, for testing. But I would simply create one separate "Test" package, with some organization, like creating individual namespaces/directories for frontend, backend, and API inside test directory.

I hope that answers the question.